# Remove additional line break tags using CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to not display/ignore all but one multiple `<br/>` tag where present and also keep the `<br/>` tag where there is only one tag present for a HTML page presented in a web browser.

I've searched around and `nth-child` comes close, but just removes all tags. Using simple CSS, how can I retain one `<br/>` tag between second paragraph and third paragraph, and the single `<br/>` tag between sixth and seventh and eight and ninth paragraphs in the example below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
br:nth-child(1n+2) {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<br/>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<br/>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the rule that you follow when you choose to hide or display `<br/>` tags?

Comment: Just leaving one <br/> between paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `br + br` for this, check updated snippet below

```css
br + br {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>The sixth paragraph.</p>
<br/>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The eight paragraph.</p>
<br/>
<p>The ninth paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant. That works great. Many thanks. Is it possible to increase the space where the <br/> tags are retained? By swapping for another tag or adding padding or something?

Comment: you can set extra gap to `p` tag

Comment: Adjusting <p> won't help me, I'm afraid. On my actual pages the text has no tags (a blog with hundreds of posts) so I only have the <br/> tags to separate the text. (Sorry for this poor practice! -- not a coder)

Comment: you can set margin on br tag.. to adjust extra gap

Comment: I've just come across places where there are exactly two <br/> tags. The break is closed for these. Not sure how that can be worked around?

Comment: Here's an example page. It appears that where there are two <br/>, the gap is closed up. 

http://www.thetweedpig.com/2017/05/dunhill-blends-in.html

I can put three Br +, but there may be a better way that makes the layout more uniform.

By the way, I tried to space where I have <b> titles.

br + br {display:none}
}

.post b 
{
display: block;
margin-top:10px; line-height:200%;
}

Not a whizz at this sort of thing, I'm afraid.